# Spring WebFlux functional router + OpenAPI UI

Tags: spring-webflux, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I would like to create OpenAPI UI spec, using Spring WebFlux functional router on Kotlin.
Spring Boot v.2.5.2, springdoc-openapi v.1.5.9.
Here is my router class:

```
@Configuration
class UserServiceRouter {

    @Bean
    @RouterOperations(
        RouterOperation(
            path = "/user/{id}",
            method = [RequestMethod.GET],
            beanClass = UserService::class,
            beanMethod = "getUserCredentialsById",
        operation = Operation(
            parameters = [Parameter(
                style = ParameterStyle.SIMPLE,
                explode = Explode.FALSE,
                `in` = ParameterIn.PATH
            )]
        )
        ),
        RouterOperation(
            path = "/user/profile/{id}",
            method = [RequestMethod.GET],
            beanClass = UserService::class,
            beanMethod = "getUserProfileById",
        operation = Operation(
            parameters = [Parameter(
                style = ParameterStyle.SIMPLE,
                explode = Explode.FALSE,
                `in` = ParameterIn.PATH
            )]
        )
    )
    fun userRoute(userServiceHandler: UserServiceHandler) = coRouter {
        ("/user").nest {
            GET("/{id}", userServiceHandler::getUserCredentialsById)
            GET("/profile/{id}", userServiceHandler::getUserById)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create a GET query like

```
http://localhost:8080/user/1
```

where 1 is my desired user`s ID.

But my OpenAPI`s UI still tries to create query with GET parameter

```
http://localhost:8080/user/{id}?id=1
```

which obviously leads to error 400.
Would be nice to know how my @RouterOperations should be configured appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct config for Path Variables looks like
(I`ve left only one GET query here for brevity):

```
@Bean
@RouterOperations(
    RouterOperation(
        path = "/user/{id}",
        method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.GET),
        beanClass = UserService::class,
        beanMethod = "getUserCredentialsById",
        operation = Operation(
            operationId =  "getUserCredentialsById",
            method = "GET",
            parameters = [
                Parameter(
                    name = "id",
                    `in` = ParameterIn.PATH,
                    style = ParameterStyle.SIMPLE,
                    explode = Explode.FALSE,
                    required = true
                )]
        )
    )
)
fun userRoute(userServiceHandler: UserServiceHandler) = coRouter {
    path("/user")
        .nest {
            GET("/{id}", userServiceHandler::getUserCredentialsById)
        }
}
```

See specs [here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#operationObject).
Important points:

- Operation ID is mandatory
- Default value in `Operation` `parameters[]` is "query parameters" instead of "path parameters" +  we should
  explicitly point parameter name (`name = "id"`) in order to override default
  behavior.
- As provided in question, `ParameterIn.PATH` is also mandatory.